# window function in superset metric custom SQL Metrics not working

Tags: apache-superset

I am trying to extract last value using window function in metrics custom SQL but it returns the first value after grouping the dimension columns is their any other way to use window function with group by clause (made by superset itself) or use window function without group by clause.